# Zend PDO issue after Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdo

I have a LAMP server set up on Ubuntu. Many Magento and MediaWiki installations were working well before I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04.

After the upgrade, attempting to load one of the pages served by my localhost raises the error `The PDO extension is required for this adapter but the extension is not loaded`

I typed `php -m` and saw that `PDO` and `pdo_mysql` are both loaded. My php version is 5.6.4. None of the installations use an individual php.ini file. I tried to add

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

to /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini but this did not affect my situation. I have also verified that the latest version of php5-mysql is installed.

Has anyone else seen this problem? Is it specific to the Ubuntu upgrade, or am I just missing a configuration setting somewhere?

**Edit: php info**

After reading Lea's answer below, I am to the point where `php -i | grep -i pdo` produces the output:

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
PDO
PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql
pdo_mysql
PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
pdo_mysql.default_socket => /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock =>     /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

The test script also runs successfully.

Comment: Check phpinfo() for the right php.ini, reload Apache, or php5-fpm etc.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already this all of these steps. However; follow step by step this guide. Sometimes we missed some little step. This works for me. I just tested it in a virtual machine using Ubuntu 15.04

### Install

```
apt-get -y update
add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
apt-get -y update
apt-get -y install php5 php5-mhash php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-cli php5-mysql php5-gd php5-intl
```

### Load Modules (`sudo vim /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`)

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

### Restart Apache

`sudo service apache2 restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

### Check if module are enabled (make sure the modules are loaded)

1. Create a php file and add:

   `<?php phpinfo();?>`
2. Or run

   `php -i | grep pdo`

### Testing

Change your `myDatabase`, `username` and `password` that match your settings.

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I think my lack of familiarity with pdo is the final part of this problem. I added the output of `php -i | grep -i pdo` above. The test script you have runs without an error. I still get pdo error messages when I try to load any of the php sites on localhost. Do I need to update my mysql databases or something else?

Comment: I am so sorry. Unfortunately, I am in the office right now, and I am not able to check this out now. Tonight I will check it and i will reply you comment.

Comment: I reinstalled php and it has fixed the issue. I still am curious where I was going wrong with fixing the issue. I prefer to not just wipe out and reinstall.

Comment: Cool! Explain how you reinstall php. That it might explain why. Did you use apt? Did you upgrade before reinstall it? Did you follow a different guide to install it, like the one i suggested?

Comment: I removed libapache2-mod-php5 and php5 then reinstalled them as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323678/repair-broken-symlinks-reinstall-php5

Comment: I think the problem was likely libapache2-mod-php5 and not php itself?

Comment: Glad that you make it work! Good luck with your project